# Clickhouse: INDEX on column with values 0 1

Tags: performance, indexing, database-performance, clickhouse

I am trying to boost the performance of a query which contains a WHERE clause on a UInt8 column, that only contains 0 or 1 as possible values. I tried to break down the problem to ensure that no other factors (partition, PK..) cause the problem. I created a simple Table *index_text* with only 1 column and a set of indizes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE default.index_text (
  `columnX` UInt8,
  INDEX indexX1 columnX TYPE minmax GRANULARITY 1,
  INDEX indexX2 columnX TYPE
  set(0) GRANULARITY 1,
    INDEX indexX3 columnX TYPE
  set(1) GRANULARITY 1
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY
  tuple() SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

After that, I populate the table with ~25mil random values (0 or 1). I would expect the indizes to drop granules on this query, but this is not the case:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM index_text WHERE columnX = 0

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM index_text
WHERE columnX = 0

[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.511085 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> executeQuery: (from [::1]:40088) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM index_text WHERE columnX = 0
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.511384 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> ContextAccess (default): Access granted: SELECT(columnX) ON default.index_text
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.511440 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> default.index_text (SelectExecutor): Key condition: unknown
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.512611 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> default.index_text (SelectExecutor): Index `indexX1` has dropped 0 / 3050 granules.
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.522601 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> default.index_text (SelectExecutor): Index `indexX2` has dropped 0 / 3050 granules.
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.523699 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> default.index_text (SelectExecutor): Index `indexX3` has dropped 0 / 3050 granules.
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.523722 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> default.index_text (SelectExecutor): Selected 1 parts by date, 1 parts by key, 3050 marks by primary key, 3050 marks to read from 1 ranges
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.523764 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> default.index_text (SelectExecutor): Reading approx. 24985600 rows with 2 streams
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.523823 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> InterpreterSelectQuery: FetchColumns -> Complete
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.525061 [ 620 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> AggregatingTransform: Aggregating
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.525087 [ 620 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> Aggregator: Aggregation method: without_key
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.530850 [ 621 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> AggregatingTransform: Aggregating
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.530893 [ 621 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> Aggregator: Aggregation method: without_key
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.598438 [ 620 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> AggregatingTransform: Aggregated. 6509826 to 1 rows (from 6.21 MiB) in 0.074525217 sec. (87350648.03635526 rows/sec., 83.30 MiB/sec.)
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.598976 [ 621 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> AggregatingTransform: Aggregated. 6109074 to 1 rows (from 5.83 MiB) in 0.075064427 sec. (81384408.62274216 rows/sec., 77.61 MiB/sec.)
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.598994 [ 621 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Trace> Aggregator: Merging aggregated data
┌──COUNT()─┐
│ 12618900 │
└──────────┘
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.599322 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Information> executeQuery: Read 24979658 rows, 23.82 MiB in 0.088181578 sec., 283275243 rows/sec., 270.15 MiB/sec.
[JWDebian] 2020.10.19 07:48:26.599356 [ 584 ] {af7615f0-f32b-47c5-87a2-e8acc8e27f5e} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage (for query): 0.00 B.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Conceptual misunderstanding of INDEX? Wrong type/params of INDEX? I am using ClickHouse server version 20.9.2 revision 54439, so I guess the *allow_experimental_data_skipping_indices* setting is no longer important. In desperation, I set it to 1 and queried an O*PTIMIZE TABLE index_text FINAL* after population, but the results are the same.

Comment: GRANULARITY 1 means your index uses one granule (index_granularity = 8192 records) per data block. During query execution clickhouse tries to skip these blocks in order to reduce number of data read from the disk.
In your example with equally randomly distributed 0/1 values it makes little sense as (almost) all granules have both zeros and ones, thus nothing to skip.

Comment: Seems that I have fallen back into SQL-thinking patterns in this case, thx! 
So it would be necessary to include the columnX in the PK/Order by to improve performance, am I right?

Comment: Yes, having columnX in primary key is the best case. Of course, devil in details - your data distribution, queries, etc., but generally it should work